# ¿Cómo crear un indice en sybase?

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo que crear un indice para una tabla en `sybase`, pero no se cual es la diferencia de crear un indice `"clustered"` o `"nonclustered".`

Comment: Entonces la pregunta no es como crear un indice, si no cual es la diferencia entre un indice clustered o noclustered?

Answer (score 2):

## Diferencia entre Índices Agrupados y No Agrupados en SQL Server

Buen día, los índices son usados para acelerar el proceso de consultas en SQL Server, resultando en alto desempeño. Son similares a índices de libros de texto. En los libros de texto, si usted necesita ir a un capítulo en particular, usted va al índice, encuentra el número de página del capítulo y va directamente a esa página. Sin índices, el proceso de encontrar su capítulo deseado habría sido muy lento.

Lo mismo aplica a los índices en bases de datos. Sin índices, un Sistema de Gestión de Bases de Datos (DBMS, por sus siglas en inglés) tiene que recorrer todos los registros en la tabla para recuperar los resultados deseados. Este proceso es llamado escaneo de tablas, y es extremadamente lento. Por otra parte, si usted crea índices, la base de datos va a ese índice primero y luego recupera los correspondientes registros de tabla directamente.

Hay dos tipos de Índices en `SQL Server:`

- Índices Agrupados
- Índices no Agrupados

## Índices Agrupados

Un índice agrupado define el orden en el cual los datos son físicamente almacenados en una tabla. Los datos de las tablas pueden ser ordenados sólo en una forma, por lo tanto, sólo puede haber un índice agrupado por tabla. En SQL Server, la restricción de llave primaria crea automáticamente un índice agrupado en esa columna en particular.

Demos un vistazo. Primero, cree una tabla “student” dentro de “schooldb” ejecutando el siguiente script:

```
CREATE DATABASE schooldb

CREATE TABLE student
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DOB datetime NOT NULL,
    total_score INT NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 )
```

Note aquí que, en la tabla “student”, hemos establecido la restricción de llave primaria en la columna “id”. Esto crea automáticamente un índice agrupado en la columna “id”. Esto crea automáticamente un índice agrupado en la columna “id”. Para ver todos los índices en una tabla particular, ejecute el procedimiento agregado “sp_helpindex”. Este procedimiento almacenado acepta el nombre de la tabla como parámetro y recupera todos los índices de la tabla. La siguiente consulta recupera los índices creados en la tabla “student”.

```
USE schooldb                    
EXECUTE sp_helpindex student
```

## Índices no Agrupados

Un índice no agrupado no ordena los datos físicos dentro de la tabla. De hecho, un índice no agrupado es agrupado en un solo lugar y los datos de la tabla son almacenados en otro lugar. Esto es similar a un libro de texto donde el contenido del libro está localizado en un lugar y el índice está localizado en otro. Esto permite tener más de un índice no agrupado por tabla.

Es importante mencionar que dentro de la tabla los datos serán ordenados por un índice agrupado. De todos modos, por dentro los datos del índice no agrupado son almacenados en un orden específico. El índice contiene valores de columna en los cuales el índice es creado y la dirección del registro a la que el valor de la columna pertenece.

Cuando una consulta es lanzada contra una columna en la cual el índice es creado, la base de datos primero irá al índice y buscará la dirección de la fila correspondiente en la tabla. Luego, irá a esa dirección de fila y obtendrá otros valores de columna. Es debido a este paso adicional que los índices no agrupados son más lentos que los índices agrupados.

**Creando un Índice No Agrupado**
La sintaxis para crear un Índice no agrupado es similar a la del índice agrupado. De todos modos, en el caso de los índices no agrupados, la palabra reservada “NONCLUSTERED” es usada en lugar de “CLUSTERED”. Revise el siguiente script.

```
use schooldb

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tblStudent_Name
ON student(name ASC)
```

---

Esta respuesta esta copiada del siguiente [enlace](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-indices-agrupados-y-no-agrupados-en-sql-server/).

Comment: ojo que la pregunta es sobre sybase, no sqlserver... aunque la teoria puede aplicar igualmente, puede que los ejemplos no.

Comment: Tienes razón @gbianchi, voy analizar mi respuesta y la editaré para que se ajuste a la pregunta, muchas gracias!

Comment: Tene en cuenta que lo que vos decis que es documentacion, no lo es, es el lugar de donde copiaste este post. Deberia decir (y lo voy a editar) copiado de, para darle al autor original los creditos que merece, y deberia ser visible.